# vanilla JS to angular directive; creating DOM elements which use angular directives

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've created the following code:

```
var node = document.getElementById('TreeList');

var keys = Object.keys(model[0]);
var trackingObject = {};

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    trackingObject[keys[i]] = "";
}

for (var i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {

        var current = keys[j];

        if (trackingObject[current] !== model[i][current]) {

            trackingObject[current] = model[i][current];

            for (var k = j+1; k < keys.length; k++) {
                trackingObject[keys[k]] = "";
            }

            var newNode = document.createElement('li');
            newNode.setAttribute("style", "padding-left: calc(10px + " + j * 20 + "px);");
            newNode.setAttribute("ng-click", "alertTest()"); //functionality test
            newNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(model[i][current]));
            node.appendChild(newNode);
        }
    }
};
```

It takes an object array `model` and create new `<li>` elements based on specific criteria. The code works as desired, however I'm having difficulty understanding how to get this into a directive. Just like the code, the directive should only require the object array input, and then render the complete `<ul>`.

Some of the `<li>` elements will contain angular directives such as `ng-click` or `ng-show`, however these don't work at the moment and I believe that is related to not using `$compile`

I understand creating a directive with a static `template` or `templateUrl` property, but I don't understand how to use my code, which creates DOM elements, in a directive.

For reference, a sample object in the array might look like this: `{ACV: "A", ACVGroup: "Reliant", FM: 1, FY: 2008}`, note: the number of properties is not static.

Comment: what do you mean by "***how to use my code, which creates DOM elements, in a directive.***" can you examplify.. like a markup you desire before and after?

Comment: Ideally, you don't create DOM elements inside your code; you include rules in your directive template that generate the desired elements based on the data in scope: `<li ng-repeat="foo in model">` etc.   (You can also generate HTML inside the directive link and use `$compile` to turn it into a usable template; functionally this is the same as putting the logic into the template in the first place except that you do it in javascript)

Comment: @DanielBeck that's how I've always gone about doing it, however the logic that I'm using precludes some items and does not create a new `<li>` for every object in the array. That's why I wasn't using `ng-repeat`

Comment: So, yeah, for that the first thing I'd try would be ng-repeat with a filter for example.

Comment: Whether an element is rendered or not depends on characteristics of the array objects before it, which is where those nested loops are coming from. Is that level of filtering possible on `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Sure, though there are potential performance issues to watch for with live filters, pre-filtering the data before feeding it to the template scope can be more efficient.    Hard to say what'd be best here without specifics, this is starting to sound like a different question now :)

Comment: @Minato what I mean is, where `ng-repeat` would create a new `<li>` for each object in the array, my code is creating the `<li`> only under certain criteria, and not for every object. In addition, my code will be adding attributes to only certain `<li>`s, also based on certain criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to include this code in the link function on the directive and include $compile where I needed to add new nodes which included more directives. I attempted to solved the problem by filtering the object array first, but and then passing it to a directive that did not need to manipulate the DOM, but I was not successful in achieving the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is based on.. [angular-toArrayFilter](https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular-toArrayFilter)

you should create a `filter` to filter out the `array` and get your filtered `array`.

```
app.filter('modelFilter', function () {
  return function (obj) {
      //obj is the repeat model here.
      //you just do the modification here
      var newObj = obj.anything() //do anything with the object
      return newObj;
  };
});
```

in your ***Markup*** simply

```
<whatever ng-repeat="item in model | modelFilter "></whatever>
```

hope this helps..